# Intersection of two spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a normed linear space and $\{a_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$ a basis for $\mathcal{B}$. Consider $b= a_1+a_2$. It can see that $\Bbb C b = \cup_i (\Bbb C b \cap \Bbb C a_i)$. Is $$\Bbb C b \cap \Bbb C a_i\neq \emptyset$$ for every $i$?

If $\Bbb C b \cap \Bbb C a_i= \emptyset$, then $\Bbb C b=\emptyset$. Also, if $\Bbb C b \cap \Bbb C a_i\neq \emptyset$, then there are $\lambda,\mu_i$ such that $\lambda b=\mu_i a_i$. Thus $b=\frac{\mu_i}{\lambda} a_i$.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathrm{span}(b)=\Bbb Cb\subset\mathrm{span}(a_1,a_2)$, so, by linear independency of the basis, it intersects all other $\Bbb Ca_i$ trivially (in the zero vector) for $i>2$.
But it also has a trivial intersection with both $\Bbb Ca_1$ and $\Bbb Ca_2$, because else, as you conclude, $a_i$ would be parallel to $b$ (scalar multiples of each other).

This also shows that the hypothesis you started off *is wrong*.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb C b\neq (\Bbb C b\cap \Bbb a_1)\cup (\Bbb C b\cap \Bbb a_2)$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Why would they be equal? Lhs. is $\Bbb Cb$, rhs. is $\{0\}$.

Comment: I think $$\Bbb C b = \Bbb C b \cap \mathcal{H}=\Bbb C b \cap (\cup_i \Bbb C a_i)= \cup_i (\Bbb C b \cap \Bbb C a_i)$$

Comment: It's not true with the union. In dimension 2, you basically claim that the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes give back the whole plane. It's true instead with the *sum* operation: $\mathcal H=\sum_i\Bbb Ca_i$ if $a_i$ is a basis.